# How to copy file path on a mac?

Tags: macos, mac, finder

Windows refugee here.  On Windows you can easily copy the path and paste it elsewhere to get to the directory.

Here is the situation on the Mac.  I am in the Finder 20 folders down and I see the file I want.  I go to my application and want to open it, so I pick Open Document from the File menu.  However, it is exceedingly difficult and time-consuming to get to the place I want.

Is there a way to copy the path in the finder and paste it in the File Open dialog of my application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can do one better: Drag the file itself into the File Open dialog of your application, and the dialog will jump to that folder, with that file highlighted, ready for you to click Open. :)

You can also right-click (hold Control and left-click, or better yet, open the Mouse pane of System Preferences and enable "Secondary Click" for your right mouse button) on the file in Finder, and click Open or Open With.

Some more helpful links:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2512

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2514

http://www.apple.com/support/switch101/

Comment: @fideli: Unnecessary perhaps, but it was a response to the "Windows refugee here" portion of the submitted question, so it's on-topic. :)

Comment: @AngryHacker: If this solves your issue (or comes closest), please mark this answer as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I use [Default Folder](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/) extensively, and if you have the Finder window open you can simply click it and it moves to that folder.

You can also "Get Info" (`Apple + I`) and under "Where:" you will see the parent folder path, which you can copy and then append the folder name to it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a great **Automator** script: http://dmevolve.com/2011/11/copying-file-paths-in-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 1):

I've used [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) to assign this script to ⌃C:

```
activate application "SystemUIServer" -- http://www.openradar.me/9406282
activate application "Finder"
set l to {}
tell application "Finder" to repeat with f in (get selection)
    set end of l to POSIX path of (f as alias)
end repeat
set text item delimiters to linefeed
set the clipboard to (l as text)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the finder, <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> usually just copies the  "name" of the file..

If, however, after copying the file in the Finder normally, you switch to `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`, and paste,_ aka_ <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, it will display the full directory Path… which you can then, more substantially… copy and Paste…  In this example, I am currently in the `global` Folder in Terminal, and then copied `index.php` in the Finder and then pasted, while in the Terminal…

```
# localadmin@dns: /Web/global >  11:42:33  :-(  
/Volumes/+10RAID2000/index.php
```

It's also worth noting that the [über-Finder-replacement, TotalFinder](http://www.binaryage.com/) adds some nice options to the Finder's contextual menus in regards to Path Copying….

[image: total finder menus]
Cheers.

**Edit**  for those of you unwilling or unlikely to use total finder, etc. there's [another nice option called PathSnagger](http://www.bergenstreetsoftware.com/category/pathsnagger/), which runs as a System service and is accessible under a contextual menu.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the non tech savvy:

1. Open TextEdit
2. Shift-Command-T to change to Plain Text mode
3. Drag the file into the window

It shows up as a path
example: /Users/Name/Desktop/...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but this got me a few times coming from Windows myself.

When you right click a folder or file, hold the `option` key, and `copy` will turn into `copy (filename) as path`.

You can extend that idea for the `copy` shortcut `CMD+C` as well. `CMD+OPT+C` copies the currently selected file or folder as a pathname.

Then to paste into another finder or choose file window, press `CMD+SHIFT+G` and paste the path in there.

Comment: Avoid posting answers to **very** old questions that already got well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.